# Creating a patch using older perforce

Tags: command-line, perforce

I am faced with the problem of sharing partial code changes between developers using an older version of perforce.

So, how can I create a patch (from a change list or a couple of changed files) using an older perforce client? Preferably from command line using one command.

Thanks.

- Client version: 2011.1
- Server version: 2007.3

Comment: Apparently this is rather a new feature implemented in perforce, although seems like a basic thing.

What seems to be a client side feature, apparently p4Eclipse doesn't know how to create a patch unless you have installed a newer p4 client. 
This puzzles me since it's a matter of saving a unified diff.

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't mind the lack of diff support in perforce since it's using its own tool to generate diffs. Too bad it's not scalable since it's available only in ultimate version.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the 'diff -du' command, which produces the unified diff format output, was added in release 2009.2. (See http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt for the history of the Perforce server)

Release 2007.3 is now quite old. Why not upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You at least could sync a clean copy of the source tree and run `diff` manually to generate a patch.  If it involves only "a couple of changed files", that shouldn't be very much work.

Comment: this involves creating a new workspace, which might be tedious should it have to be done often. also the new workspace needs to be synced each time a patch is created.

Comment: @Raul: You could write a script that extracts each edited file in a given changeset, run `p4 print FILE#have > /tmp/FILE`, and then runs `diff -du` on each of those files. (Some additional care would be needed for added files.)